# How to write a C# Program with a custom method that writes user input to text file?

Tags: c#

Edit- Based on Steve and Marco's replies I've edited the code. In the lessons the professor has used StreamWriter so I believe he probably wants us to the same. Here is the revised code:

```
 using System;
 using System.IO;

 namespace Assignment4
  {
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        FavoriteNumber();
      }
         static void FavoriteNumber()
        {
         Console.WriteLine("Please input your favorite number: ");

         var result = Console.ReadLine();

         using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("FavoriteNumber.txt"))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(result);
            }
      }

   }
  }
```

I am taking a Computer Programming Fundamentals class as a GenEd requirement for an unrelated degree, meaning I am very much a novice at this and really was just interested in gaining a very basic understanding of how it all works. That being said, this is probably a very simple question for most users on this forum. The instructions for this assignment are as follows:

"Write a C# program which uses a custom method to accept user input and save the input to a text file."

Can someone please tell me if the code I wrote meets these parameters? I was really lost with this assignment but am hoping that by some miracle I got it right. Thank you in advance for your help!

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Assignment4
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
      }  

          static void addNumbers(int x, int y)
          {
            int result = x+y;

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Assignment4.txt"))
            {
               writer.WriteLine(result);  
            }
          }      
   }
}
```

Comment: No, you are missing this part: _accept user input_ you need to write the code to receive the input from your user (Console.ReadLine) and pass this input to your custom method.

Comment: Thank you, Steve. I appreciate the reply, as well as the comment linking to information regarding homework questions. I've been downvoted on this question and was hoping you could help me understand what I can do to improve my questions in the future should I need to post again. I believe I followed the guidelines (e.g. made an effort to do the work on my own), so if you could give me some input that would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: But you haven't done anything about the _accept user input_ part. This is probably the reason for the downvotes. Some help about getting user input https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I appreciate your quick reply. I thought I did accept user input when I added (Console.ReadLine) to the custom method in the code I added to the original post via an edit. Was this incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

You need to accept user input somewhere. You can do that with `Console.ReadLine()`. It waits until the user types in something and then continues.
Also, you do not need a StreamWriter for this. You can just use `File.WriteAllText()`

The result would look something like this:

```
static void WriteTextToFile()
{
    WriteTextToFile();
}

static void WriteTextToFile()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter some value:");
    var valueToWrite = Console.ReadLine();

    File.WriteAllText("Assignment4.txt", valueToWrite);

    Console.WriteLine("Thanks alot. Press a key to close.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems?cb=1) and also [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Thank you Marco, I've edited the code in the original question. I used StreamWriter since that's what the Professor has used. Is it accepting input correctly now?